# Updating upon a join

Tags: sql, sql-update

I can simply use a select statment on a join to pull results I'd Like using:

```
Select * from RESULTS (NOLOCK) left join orders on Results.ordno = orders.ordno 
left join folders on folders.folderno = orders.folderno 
left join pranaparms on folders.prodcode = pranaparms.prodcode and results.analyte = pranaparms.analyte  
WHERE Results.s <> 'OOS-A' and Results.Final Between pranaparms.LOWERQCLIMIT  and pranaparms.UPPERQCLIMIT and (pranaparms.LOWERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL and pranaparms.UPPERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL) 
and results.ordno in (1277494)
```

However, is there a convenient way which I could do an update on the selected fields?

I have tried this so far:

```
Update RESULTS (NOLOCK) left join orders on Results.ordno = orders.ordno 
left join folders on folders.folderno = orders.folderno 
left join pranaparms on folders.prodcode = pranaparms.prodcode and results.analyte = pranaparms.analyte  
set Results.S = 'OOS-B'  
WHERE Results.s <> 'OOS-A' and Results.Final Between pranaparms.LOWERQCLIMIT  and pranaparms.UPPERQCLIMIT and (pranaparms.LOWERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL and pranaparms.UPPERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL) 
and results.ordno in (1277494)
```

However, it is passing an error indicating `"Incorrect syntax near '('"`
Is there a way for me to update off of this join or will I need to do tables individually?

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` syntax suggests SQL Server.  The correct `update` syntax in SQL Server is:

```
update r 
    set S = 'OOS-B'  
    from results r left join
         orders o
         on r.ordno = o.ordno left join
         folders f
         on f.folderno = o.folderno left join
         pranaparms p
         on f.prodcode = p.prodcode and r.analyte = p.analyte  
    where r.s <> 'OOS-A' and
          r.Final Between p.LOWERQCLIMIT and p.UPPERQCLIMIT and
          (p.LOWERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL and p.UPPERQCLIMIT IS NOT NULL) and
          r.ordno in (1277494);
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.
- Do not use `NOLOCK` unless you know what you are doing.  Given that you don't know the syntax rules for `update` for the database you are using, I will guess that you don't understand locks either.
- Your `WHERE` conditions are turning the outer joins into inner joins.  You should just specify the correct `join` type -- and probably move the conditions to the `on` clauses.  I've left the logic as you wrote it.